# Excel formulae to use different worksheets i.e worksheet 4, can use worksheet 1, 2 0r 3

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook. WorkBook contains 4 worksheets. On the 4 th worksheet, i would like it to have functionality to be  using different worksheets i.e worksheets 1,2 or 3 as reference for calculations.[workbook with 4 worksheets, 3 are references for values on 4 th worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwnmA.png)

Comment: Yes it's possible, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Just like referring to a cell: `=A1` you can refer to a cell on a specific sheet: `'Sheet1'!A1` or `'B2B23'!A1`

Comment: Thanks P.b.  The difficult part is activating the different reference worksheets from the main sheet i.e in this case temp-23C worksheet. So its like before i up load data on the main sheet i activate a specific  reference worksheet , next time i would use a different reference for calculated values on the main sheet too.

Comment: I dont know if this is possible, or i should resort to alternative programming

Comment: You could look I to INDIRECT() or better is to select the formula cells and `ctrl+H` replace the old sheet name for the new one here. Probably better solution, since INDIRECT will recalculate at each change in the workbook.

Comment: cheers , i will try the INDIRECT()